# Variable not in scope: a

Tags: haskell, scope, pattern-matching, mergesort

I m trying to make a simple merge sort function. Almost finished with the code, but:

```
m_sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
m_sort d
     | d == [] = []
     | d == [a] = [a]
     | otherwise = merge (m_sort (fst $ split d)) (m_sort (snd $ split d))
```

for some reason here i get `Haskell_training.hs:137:21: error: Variable not in scope: a`. Excluding the `| d == [a] = [a]` leads to nice compilation, but it won't work without it. Is there some really obvious problem with pattern matching I'm not seeing?

Comment: `d == [a]` is not pattern matching (its an expression) so of course it may not bind variables. You probably want `| [a] <- d = ...` which *is* pattern matching. Aside: even though `d == []` compiles, you should write `[] <- d` (or `null d`) instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there some really obvious problem with pattern matching I'm not seeing?

Yes, sure: you haven't written a pattern match! (Okay, you wrote a trivial one, `d`, which matches anything and names it `d`.) What you wrote instead was a guard, which must be an expression of type `Bool`. While `d == [a]` is syntactically okay, and could potentially have type `Bool` if `d` and `a` have appropriate types, it doesn't work here because you don't have any `a` to compare `d` to.

You probably wanted this instead:

```
m_sort [] = []
m_sort [a] = [a]
m_sort d = merge ...
```

Now instead of having an expression that has the term `[a]` in it referring to some variable named `a`, this will be a pattern match, which looks for a term with the shape of a one-element list and binds `a` to that element.

Comment: Thanks, surprisingly the difference between `length(d) == 1` and `length(d) == a` was never important in previous 30+ problems i solved, so I'm kinda lucky to stumble upon this. Could be a big misunderstanding in the future((

Comment: @AndrewS. I find your comment a bit confusing. `length d == 1` and `length d == a` are pretty significantly different; and also my answer doesn't mention `length` at all!

Comment: "a guard, which must be an expression of type Bool" - technically false, due to [pattern guards](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard).

Comment: @user2407038 Okay, that's fair. I'm not sure adding the language to be precise there will make the explanatory power of the answer better, though, so I'll leave it and upvote your comment to encourage the interested reader to dive into the precise rules.

Answer (score 0):

Iirc, that's not pattern matching - you're asking if `d` is equal to `[a]`, and as you've not defined what `a` is that's causing issues.

Remember you need an expression evaluating to `Bool` as the condition in a guard, so something like `length(d) == 1` should work:

```
m_sort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
m_sort d
     | d == []        = []
     | length d  == 1 = d
     | otherwise      = merge (m_sort (fst $ split d)) (m_sort (snd $ split d))
```

Alternatively you can declare your function as multiple pieces (which I think is better practice anyway), as in @DanielWagner's answer, which will let you use pattern matching like you're trying to.

Comment: you probably want something like `null . tail $ d` instead of `length d` since `length` needs to evaluate the entire list while we only care if it has more than one element.

Comment: @puhlen Oooh, nice - I won't edit, as I think `length` is clearer and efficiency probably isn't of much concern here, but +1 so they'll hopefully see the more efficient way. Proper pattern matching is the best approach in this case, this is just hopefully explaining why OP's current approach *doesn't* work.

Comment: `length` is clear but it's inefficient.  There might be a better way than my suggestion as it was just off the top of my head, but I would use pattern matching for this anyway.  If I needed some sort of length check like this I'd probably write an appropriately named function for it (if one doesn't already exist) so I can have both clarity and efficiency.